# Same mapWithState Function used by several JavaDStreams

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have 2 JavaPairDStreams. They have the same key(type and value) and the same value type (different value). I need them to share the same state to return a result based the current state, so I use the same mapWithState function.

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> inputMessagesStream = readFromKafkaStream1();
JavaPairDStream<String, String> inputMessagesStream2 = readFromKafkaStream();
Function3<String, Optional<String>, State<MessageState>, String> messageState = (key, value, state) -> {
                if (state.exists()) {
                    return state.get().process(value.get());
                } else {
                    MessageState ms = new MessageState();
                    ms.process(value.get());
                    state.update(ms);
                    return null;
                }
            };

JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, String, MessageState, String> message1 = inputMessagesStream.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(messageState));
JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, String, MessageState, String> message2 = inputMessagesStream2.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(messageState));
```

Is it ok to use the same function for 2 different streams? Is the state updated correctly and shared by each stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This function doesn't *close over* state (or anything else), it gets it as an argument. So these two uses will get different states from different streams' `mapWithState`.

Comment: Just to be sure that I undestrood the answer: Although the mapWithState function can be used for more JavaPairDStreams, the State object is not shared between the streams. Every stream has it's own state obj, correct?

Comment: Streams in general don't have any "state objects". `mapWithState` creates a special kind of stream which does have state objects (one for each key). Of course, calling it twice will create streams with separate state (even if you call it twice on a single stream).

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine `inputMessagesStream`  and `inputMessagesStream2` as

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> combinedStream = inputMessagesStream.union(inputMessagesStream2);
```

To differentiate the above 2 streams, you can define some flag and add it to `MapWithState`

```
JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, String, MessageState, String> message = combinedStream.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(messageState));
```

It will work.